# ImageTk and PIL do not display png image correctly

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to write some kind of mapping tool in python using both the PIL and Tkinter module. So far almost everything works quite fine. During the setup process of the ui a virtual image is created (based upon several input png files), which also seems to have worked well. However, when trying to display this picture inside a canvas using ImageTk.Photo the display shows something that is definitly not the picture. For debugging reasons I had my picture be output by using the show method on the PIL.Image itself.

However what the show method shows and the canvas displays somehow differ - I could not figure out the solution and would appreciate help.

First of all the code excerts (I only show the initialization of the canvas and the displaying of the picture, since the whole code would be extremly long and not provide any more inside I guess).

This is the code excert of the initialization of the canvas (I display a completly black picture until the user loaded all resources neccessary for displaying the picture):

```
    self.tileset_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=1024, height=1024)
    self.tileset_canvas.create_line(0, 0, 80, 80)
    self.tileset_raw_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PImage.new("RGB", (1024, 1024), "black"))
    self.tileset_canvas_image = self.tileset_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.tileset_raw_image)
    self.tileset_canvas.grid(row=4, column=6, sticky=tkinter.W)
```

Furthermore inside another method I change the display of the image:

```
        merged_img = PImage.new("RGB", (128, 512))
        merged_img.paste(tsp_img, (0, 0))
        merged_img.paste(tss_img, (0, 320))
        merged_img = merged_img.resize((1024, 1024)) #Double the view for a better mapping expierience
        merged_img = merged_img.convert(mode="RGB")
        self.tileset_raw_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(merged_img)
        merged_img.show()
        self.tileset_canvas.itemconfig(self.tileset_canvas_image, image=self.tileset_raw_image)
```

As you can see I also call the show method to see what the picture actually looks like.

This is what the show method outputs, when called on the picture:
[image: Output of show method]

However this is what is shown inside the ui:
[image: Output in the ui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that cares, it seems that the image was not just correctly anchored but instead fixed in the middle of the canvas.